# Prevent "inherited" signal handlers from executing

Tags: qt, signals, qml, handler, qtquick2

Defining a signal handler in a "base" component is pretty nifty when that functionality is going to be frequently used by many derived components.

However, in QML installing a new handler in a derived component **does not** replace the original handler, it merely stacks on top of it. As handlers are not really unique per signal, they are merely connections, and you can have multiple connections per signal.

One solution is to simply not provide a default handler in the base component, but then you have to copy and paste the handler each and every time a component is used. So is there a better way?

Comment: Well, you could still define the piece of code in a function, and let subclasses simply invoke the function. Or provide some boolean property to prevent the superclass handler to do anything...

Comment: Somehow, the idea of "nifty" sounds wrong. If a signal issued by the base class is needed by the base class implementation to maintain a consistent state, then it should not be possible to override it in a derived component as this will break the design of the base class. If however the slot is not needed by the base class but only saves occasionally some text lines in the derived component, then it sounds like bad design to make the connection in the base class. I think, you should really think over the encapsulation / design of your classes.

Comment: @Jens - the problem is not the component design, but the limitations of QML. Overriding doesn't really work as expected, signal interface is limited to connect/disconnect, the latter requiring expression reference to work. I don't know where you get the funny idea that overriding base class implementations "breaks" stuff - it is something heavily used all the time. The base type defines the interface and some functionality, derived types build on that. In this case, the base component signal is a part of the interface, and it provides a default implementation.

Comment: @Jens - in my particular case, the signal was a `signal click (key)` designed for handling my custom event propagation scheme. 90% of the time, objects are in lists, so using the arrows to navigate resorts to the default implementation - get the index of the current item and go to the previous or next item. But the other 10% of the time objects are not in lists, but composed in arbitrary structure, so this behavior needs to be overriden to something very context specific. Those 90% make the default implementation a good thing, those other 10% mandate the need to completely override it.

Comment: You are probably thinking "typical QML usage" which is simple and pretty much of fixed structure, making it possible to predetermine and implement static component behavior. However, there is no such thing as fixed structure in the project I am working on, the structure is dynamic and defined by the user during the runtime, so the component design needs to be flexible and highly dynamic in order to work with the arbitrary and changing application structure.

Answer (score 1):

As peppe mentioned, one solution would be to instead of installing the handler directly, just make the handler a call to a function that can be overriden. However, function overriding itself is a mixed bag, when there is intent to reuse base implementations in the derived components, not necessarily in the order handlers stack with component inheritance.

I actually came up with a flexible, albeit a little clunky solution. It is to manually disconnect the previous installed handler and manually connect a new one. This has two implications:

1. The handlers cannot be anonymous expressions, they have to implemented as functions so they can be referenced for disconnect.
2. The handlers cannot be bound using the declarative syntax (`onSignal: handler()`), as this doesn't connect to the handler function, but to an anonymous expression which invokes the handler function. So you can't disconnect.

So it looks something like this:

```
//BaseComp.qml
QtObject {
    signal sig(int i)
    function baseHandler(i) {...}
    Component.onCompleted: sig.connect(baseHandler)
}

//DerivedComp.qml
BaseComp {
    function derivedHandler(i) {...}
    Component.onCompleted: {
        sig.disconnect(baseHandler)
        sig.connect(derivedHandler)
    }
}
```

The basic pattern is disconnect the previous base handler in every derived component which overrides it. This way you get to access the base handlers from the derived components if there is a need to do that, if instead there is only one overridden handler function, the base implementations will not be accessible from the derived classes due to how overriding is implemented in QML (there will be two identically named functions as members of the object, but both of them will refer to the derived component override).

It would be niceand useful if QML provided a pretty way to make a "unique" binding - something that purges all previous connections before making the new one. Then all that workaround code would not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Given that when overriding functions in QML, [the base implementation is no more available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875085/resolving-property-and-function-overrides-in-qml) such that there must be a distinct name for each implementation.

First define a naming scheme for slot handler functions, let's say *onSomethingHappened* executes ***handle***OnSomethingHappened. And `ComponentA`'s implementation is ***handle***OnSomethingHappened**_ComponentA**. In `handleOnSomethingHappened` there is ***superHandle***OnSomethingHappened, which executes the base class' implementation.

With these naming conventions we can achieve a setup with a bunch of nice properties:

1. Multiple inheritance possible
2. base class' implementation can optionally be called at any specific point
3. A class must only know its direct base class
4. Caller code is nicer than implementation
5. It is complex but not complicated (and [Complex is better than complicated.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))
6. I guess it can be code-generated easily

In the first example we have 3 Buttons that handle clicks, 1. using the default implementation, 2. using a custom implementation and 3. using a custom implementation plus the base implementation (at any point):

```
BaseButton {
    text: "Button 1"
}

BaseButton {
    text: "Button 2"
    handleOnClicked: function() {
        console.log("Custom click handler")
    }
}

BaseButton {
    text: "Button 3"
    handleOnClicked: function() {
        console.log("Custom click handler")
        superHandleOnClicked()
    }
}
```

This can be done by defining `BaseButton` like this

```
Button {
    property var handleOnClicked: superHandleOnClicked

    // "super" from the instance's perspective. Use this in implementations of handleOnDoubleClicked
    property var superHandleOnClicked: handleOnClicked_BaseButton

    function handleOnClicked_BaseButton() {
        console.log("BaseButton clicked.")
    }

    onClicked: handleOnClicked()
}
```

The base implementation is available in the function `superHandleOnClicked`.

**Slots with arguments**

When arguments are used, nothing changes:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 40
    color: "green"
    BaseMouseArea {
    }
}

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 40
    color: "green"
    BaseMouseArea {
        handleOnDoubleClicked: function(mouse) {
            console.log("Custom click handler", mouse.x, mouse.y)
        }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 40
    color: "green"
    BaseMouseArea {
        handleOnDoubleClicked: function(mouse) {
            console.log("Custom click handler", mouse.x, mouse.y)
            superHandleOnDoubleClicked(mouse)
        }
    }
}
```

with BaseMouseArea defined as

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent

    property var handleOnDoubleClicked: superHandleOnDoubleClicked

    // "super" from the instance's perspective. Use this in implementations of handleOnDoubleClicked
    property var superHandleOnDoubleClicked: handleOnDoubleClicked_BaseMouseArea

    function handleOnDoubleClicked_BaseMouseArea(mouse) {
        console.log("BaseMouseArea clicked", mouse.x, mouse.y, ".")
    }

    onDoubleClicked: handleOnDoubleClicked(mouse)
}
```

**Multiple inheritance**

Now we have `instance` *is a* `PointerMouseArea` *is a* `BaseMouseArea`, with instance being defined as

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 40
    color: "blue"
    PointerMouseArea {
    }
}

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 40
    color: "blue"
    PointerMouseArea {
        handleOnDoubleClicked: function(mouse) {
            console.log("Don't tell father and grandfather", mouse.x, mouse.y)
        }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 40
    color: "blue"
    PointerMouseArea {
        handleOnDoubleClicked: function(mouse) {
            console.log("Tell father and grandfather", mouse.x, mouse.y)
            superHandleOnDoubleClicked(mouse)
        }
    }
}
```

which requires the following definition of `PointerMouseArea`:

```
BaseMouseArea {
    cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor

    superHandleOnDoubleClicked: handleOnDoubleClicked_PointerMouseArea

    function handleOnDoubleClicked_PointerMouseArea(mouse, superImplementation) {
        console.log("Pointed at something") // I just add my comment and then call super
        handleOnDoubleClicked_BaseMouseArea(mouse)
    }
}
```

What you see in PointerMouseArea is

1. It adds some properties over BaseMouseArea (cursor shape)
2. It overrides the `super*` methods to it's concrete implementation
3. It implements its concrete implementation and calls the parents implementation

The foll sample project is available here: https://github.com/webmaster128/derived-qml-slots

Comment: We can override functions, it is just a rather destructive process when it comes to the function being overridden. This approach seems to pretty much be an extended version of this brief solution to overrides : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875085/resolving-property-and-function-overrides-in-qml  On a side note, it would have been nice if QML properly supported those simple and widely useful programming concepts instead of having to resort to such clunky manual solutions that are more suited back to the days of C, heck I actually use manual lifetime management, cuz refcounting is bugged

Comment: @ddriver Thanks for the hint. I fixed the statement about overriding functions. But the consequences remain unchanged. You are right with your side note, but well – nothing we can easily change.