# Qml override OnCustomValueChanged

Tags: qt, qml

I have a custom Item (MyItem) which have an "onValueChanged" function.

In another file, I declare a MyItem object and I want to override the "onValueChanged" without using the original "onValueChanged" function.

Here my code:

MyItem.qml

```
Item
{
    property real value: 5

    onValueChanged: console.log("value changed from MyItem")
}
```

main.qml

```
MyItem
{
    id: test_
    onValueChanged: console.log("value changed from test")
}

Button
{
    id: myButton_
    text: "Change value"
    onClicked: test_.value = 42
}
```

If I click on myButton_ I have the following output :

> qml: value changed from MyItem
>
> qml: value changed from test

But I want to following output:

> qml: value changed from test

It is a way to do this ?

Comment: Is it possible if you just didn't place the call `onValueChanged: console.log("value changed from MyItem")` in the first place... or did you plan to have more complex code situated there...?

Comment: Thank for your answer. What do you mean by "in the first place" ?

And yeah, I plan to use it in a mode complex situation...

Comment: Hmm... ok. This poses problems. What would be the main way of differentiating if you wanted to call the local `onValueChanged` in `myItem.qml` versus the call to `onValueChanged` in `main.qml`? They're both handling the same variable, the same symbol...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948874/prevent-inherited-signal-handlers-from-executing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496742/how-to-disconnect-the-method-for-a-signal-in-qml

Comment: @dtech, thanks, I could solve my problem :)