# Avoiding name collisions in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

While learning QML, I want to learn a good style from the beginning.
However, I already encountered some problems when it comes to naming, and I can't find something like "world-acclaimed" coding conventions, that not only cover the order of your statements, but also some good naming conventions
(as found here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-best-practices-coding.html).

The problems I find are as follows:
properties, IDs, (model)roles - they can all clash pretty easy, especially as the IDs and roles are present through multiple layers of items.

So are there any good guidelines on how to name your:

- properties
- roles
- IDs
- functions
- function variables
- components

that have proved worthy in the field?

Comment: It's not much different from C++, where in a given class all members must have unique names (overloading aside). Treat roles, properties, and functions as belonging to one namespace. IDs can always be resolved independently, they form a namespace of their own.

Answer (score 2):

QML already enforces some naming conventions - types must begin with capital letter, properties must begin with lower case letter, etc.

Unfortunately, QML elements come with quite a lot of stuff to them, and it is often the case where you get naming conflicts. In that case the "innermost declaration" seems to take precedence when resolving stuff, that is your own declarations will shadow stock properties, and there is no way to address those anymore, unlike in C++ where you can `BaseType::stuff`. I have outlined a possible approach in case you need to override and still access "inherited" members [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875085/resolving-property-and-function-overrides-in-qml).

If all you need is to avoid clashes - prepending something works very well. The most basic way is to use the underscore as in `_something` - QML's stuff never begins with an underscore, so there is no danger of clashing. For types, I prepend a character as well, which is also useful to sort/group components in the project tree view, I prepend `U_Something` - U for UI, C for core, P for prototype and so on. Same old approach that has been used through perpetuity in programming, especially in languages that don't have classes, namespaces and such and the only way to avoid conflicts is to use names such as `VK_ERROR_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED` quite common in C APIs such as Vulkan.