# Calling QML ancestor method from descendant method of same name

Tags: qt, qml, ancestor

I am trying to improve upon the SoundEffect class included with QML.  My new "MySoundEffect.qml" is show below.  However, I cannot figure out how to call the identically named "play" method of the SoundEffect class from within my own method.  My attempt below fails:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.12

SoundEffect {
    function play() {
        console.log("Play clicked in my sound effect")
        SoundEffect.play()
    }
}
```

The obvious answer is pick a new name for my method, but I'm hoping there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: This has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875085/resolving-property-and-function-overrides-in-qml), for instance). The answer is unfortunately QML doesn't support that functionality, even though it would be really useful. You will need your derived object function to use a different name from the base object function if you want one to call the other.

Answer (score 0):

The answered linked by JarMan - answers why it's not possible as I asked.  However, wrapping the ancestor class allows me too make the change transparently to rest of program:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.12

Item {
    property alias source  : effect.source
    property alias loops : effect.loops
    property alias volume : effect.volume
    property alias muted : effect.muted
    
    SoundEffect {
        id: effect
    }
    
    function play() {
        effect.play()
    }
}
```