# How to override a function, but call the base-object's version with no object id

Tags: qt, qml

I'm sure that you can do this, but I can't find how.

I need to override the **open()** method in a **Popup**-derived object in order to pass it a parameter. Here is a minimized sample of main.qml:

```
// main.qml
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Window 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
    
    Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: "Call a base-object's function in an override"
    
        MyPopup {
            id: mypopup
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    
        Button {
            text: "Say hi."
            onClicked: mypopup.open("hi")
        }
    }
```

And here is my new object, derived from **Popup**:

```
// MyPopup.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Popup {
    Text {
        id: greeting
        text: "bye"
    }

    function open( newText ) {
        greeting.text = newText
        Popup.open()                  <-- This is what I can't figure out
    }
}
```

If the base object had an **id**, then I would use it here, but the base class, **Popup**, is not instantiated. So how would I access its version of **open()**?

When I tried **Popup.open()**, as above, I was met with the error:

```
qrc:/MyPopup.qml:12: TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

When I tried **Popup:open()**, I got:

```
qrc:/MyPopup.qml:0: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

which means the derived version of **open()** was calling itself.

So how do I call Popup's version of open()?

Comment: Found this possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33890735/4069062

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QML does not allow to override functions, it can only be customized by changing or creating properties and creating new functions.

On the other hand the ids have a scope so it is valid to set ids in the components and these will have meaning in the component.

In your case there are the following possible solutions:

1. Create a new function:

**MyPopup.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Popup {
    id: root
    property alias text: greeting.text
    Text {
        id: greeting
        text: "bye"
    }
    function foo(newText){
        greeting.text = newText
        root.open()
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
// ...
onClicked: mypopup.foo("hi")
// ...
```

2. Expose the text as a new property (such as via an alias)

**MyPopup.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Popup {
    id: root
    property alias text: greeting.text
    Text {
        id: greeting
        text: "bye"
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
// ...
Button {
    text: "Say hi."
    onClicked: {
        mypopup.text = "hi"
        mypopup.open()
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Wow! really? Can't do it? I believe you, of course, but I'm surprised.

Comment: I will go with your first suggestion, but I was hoping to minimize changes to existing code (not having to change every "open()" to a new name in every module). My only issue with your second option is that it will expose internals to MyPopup that other programmers won't need or want to know.